# How can I pass a buffer, consisting of uniform arrays, from Three JS into the vertex shader?

Tags: javascript, opengl, three.js, glsl, react-three-fiber

I am using React, React Three Fiber

I have been passing along uniforms from javascript in the following way:

```
  const uniforms = useMemo(() => ({

    uTime: {
      value: 0.0
    },
    uRadius: {
      value: radius
    },
    uPointSizes: {
      value: pointSizes
    },
    uRandomValuesX: {
      value: randomValuesX
    },
    uRandomValuesY: {
      value: randomValuesY
    },
    uRandomValuesZ: {
      value: randomValuesZ
    },
    uResolutionWidth: {
      value: screen.width
    },
    uResolutionHeight: {
      value: screen.height
    }

  }), [])

...

      <points ref={gPoints}>
        <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
            <bufferAttribute
                attach="attributes-position"
                count={positions.length / 3}
                array={positions}
                itemSize={3}
                usage={THREE.DynamicDrawUsage}
            />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <shaderMaterial
            depthWrite={false}
            fragmentShader={fragmentShader}
            vertexShader={vertexShader}
            uniforms={uniforms}
            blending={THREE.AdditiveBlending}
        />
      </points>
```

And below is how I imported the uniforms in the vertex shader section:

```
const vertexShader = `
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

uniform float uTime;
uniform float uPointSizes[1000];
uniform float uRandomValuesX[1000];
uniform float uRandomValuesY[1000];
uniform float uRandomValuesZ[1000];
uniform float uRadius;
```

I have hit a problem though where the max amount of uniforms I can pass over is 4095. I want to pass over large float arrays, I have read in other places that I need to pass along several buffers, because each buffer also has a maximum size. So if I have 4 arrays and each is 10,000 in length I would want to pass along 4 buffers? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Uniform arrays can't be that big. I suggest using a [`DataTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/DataTexture) instead.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If I use DataTexture can I pass that along into the shaders? From the examples I found online it's used to create a `texture` to use with a `map={}` function, wouldn't it be using CPU to draw everything instead of the GPU? Im new please don't rip me apart in the comments, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: *"wouldn't it be using CPU to draw everything instead of the GPU"* - No. Why do you suspect that?

Comment: If each point primitive has its own size and random values, then why not use vertex attributes? (or actually 1 attribute of type `vec4`)

Comment: @Rabbid7 would I go about doing that via the ThreeJS `.setAttribute` method? I was thinking of doing something along the lines of 


`geometryRef.setAttribute("array1", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(array1, 3));`

I'm just not sure how to do that in React using R3F, or if that is the correct solution